# Turning on/off and saving update of Bullseye

Tags: bullseye

I want to use bullseye code coverage in my dos script.
And I have written below code. The test.cov file is created but result is not generated on test.cov.

```
SET MY_LOCAL_COV_FILE=c:\test.cov
SET COVFILE=%MY_LOCAL_COV_FILE%
SET COVBUILDZONE=%BUILD_NUMBER% 
covselect --file "%MY_LOCAL_COV_FILE%" --add c:
cov01 --on
MSBuild ".\my.sln" /t:clean /p:Configuration="Debug"
cov01 --off
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems.

1. You are not building the code, you have only run the 'clean' target from MSBuild, try running 'rebuild' which will clean and then compile the code so the code coverage instrumentation is inserted.
2. You are not running the built code so Bullseye can't get any meaningful coverage information. Before the 'conv01 --off' try running your executable, or unit test, or whatever it is you have built.